# javascript displaying current time

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code to displayng current date and time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tday  =new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

function GetClock(){
d = new Date();
nday   = d.getDay();
nmonth = d.getMonth();
ndate  = d.getDate();
nyear = d.getYear();
nhour  = d.getHours();
nmin   = d.getMinutes();
nsec   = d.getSeconds();

if(nyear<1000) nyear=nyear+1900;
if(nhour ==  0) {ap = " AM";nhour = 12;} 
else if(nhour <= 11) {ap = " AM";} 
else if(nhour == 12) {ap = " PM";} 
else if(nhour >= 13) {ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;}

if(nmin <= 9) {nmin = "0" +nmin;}
if(nsec <= 9) {nsec = "0" +nsec;}


document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
}
window.onload=GetClock;
</script>
<div id="clockbox"></div>
```

So I want to replace "PM" and "AM" with some images. Can anybody help me to deal with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, in essence, you are asking how to create images in html?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ap == ' AM') {
    ap = " <img src='/path/to/am.png'>";
} else {
    ap = " <img src='/path/to/pm.png'>";
}
```

Stick that right before the `document.getElementById` line, after customizing the src'es of the two image tags.